# Is it possible use controller with different namespace in route group ?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Is it possible use controller with different namespace in route group ?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'namespace' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['namespace'=>'Controllers','uses'=>'SiteController@dashobard']);
    Route::get('posts', 'PostsController@index');
});
```

Comment: `"uses" => "\\NameSpace\\Controller@function"` should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TimLewis has mentioned in the comments it is possible.

(Assuming the full namespace for `SiteController` is `App\Http\Controllers`) The following should work:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'namespace' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', '\App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@dashboard');
    Route::get('posts', 'PostsController@index');
});
```

However, it would make more sense to split the routes up:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'SiteController@dashboard');

    Route::group(['namespace' => 'admin'], function () {
        Route::get('posts', 'PostsController@index');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!